# Mixing MIDI audio channels using CoreAudio in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, mixer, coremidi

I'm trying to write a program which will receive MIDI signals from different instruments. Currently the MIDI signals are sent to sampler units (kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler) each with a associated sound effect - supplied by sound fonts. Individually I can get the instruments to play correctly however I need to be able to mix multiple instruments.

At first I thought about just creating a separate AUGraph for each track but I imagine that this would use a lot of memory and isn't the best solution.

Since then I've been trying to get an audio mixer to work (kAudioUnitSubType_AU3DMixerEmbedded). After setting up the other audio units (which I've tested) I set up the mixer using the following code:

```
cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AU3DMixerEmbedded;

result = AUGraphAddNode (_processingGraph, &cd, &mixerNode);
NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to add the Output unit to the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
```

Then I opened the graph:

```
result = AUGraphOpen (_processingGraph);
NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to open the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
```

Next I set up the stream description:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription desc;

desc.mSampleRate = 44100; // set sample rate
desc.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
desc.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
desc.mBitsPerChannel = sizeof(AudioSampleType) * 8; // AudioSampleType == 16 bit signed ints
desc.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
desc.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
desc.mBytesPerFrame = ( desc.mBitsPerChannel / 8 ) * desc.mChannelsPerFrame;
desc.mBytesPerPacket = desc.mBytesPerFrame * desc.mFramesPerPacket;
```

Finally I connected all the nodes together:

```
result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (_processingGraph, mixerNode, 0, ioNode, 0);
NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Unable to interconnect the nodes in the audio processing graph. Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(_processingGraph, samplerNode, 0, mixerNode, 0); 

NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Couldn't connect mixer output(0) to outputNode (0). Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);

result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(_processingGraph, drumSamplerNode, 0, mixerNode, 1);

NSCAssert (result == noErr, @"Couldn't connect speech synth unit output (0) to mixer input (1). Error code: %d '%.4s'", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
```

I connect the mixer to the io-unit. The first sampler to input bus 0 on the mixer and the second sampler to the second input bus on the sampler. Here's a copy of the CAShow:

```
  Member Nodes:
node 1: 'aumu' 'samp' 'appl', instance 0x8882210 O  
node 2: 'aumu' 'samp' 'appl', instance 0x88819d0 O  
node 3: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x8883510 O  
node 4: 'aumx' '3dem' 'appl', instance 0x8a5d5d0 O  
  Connections:
node   4 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 1 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]
node   1 bus   0 => node   4 bus   0  [ 1 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]
node   2 bus   0 => node   4 bus   1  [ 1 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]
    CurrentState:
mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isRunning=F
```

When I initialise the graph I get an OSStatus -10868. I've seen examples which use ring buffers and render callbacks. Is this necessary when using MIDI or only when getting input from a live device like a mic? What I'd really like to know if my general approach is possible (i.e. it should work fine but I've made some small mistake somewhere) or if I need to spend several hours reading about ring buffers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ring buffers or renderCallbacks if you just want to send msgs to the AUSamplers. You just send it a msg:

```
OSStatus result = noErr;
UInt32 noteNum = 60;
UInt32 onVelocity = 100;
UInt32 noteCommand =    kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;
result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (sampler.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0);
```

I've seen that error code before but I forget what it means. There is an order that you need to follow when you set things up. Check out audioGraph ([docs](http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html)) ([source](https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph)). I'd suggest setting up your RemoteIO & Mixer first - makes more sense when looking at the CAShow() output.

Also, by default a mixer has only one input. If you want more, you need to specify it:

```
// set the bus count
UInt32 numBuses = busCount;
result = AudioUnitSetProperty(mixerUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              0, 
                              &numBuses, 
                              sizeof(numBuses));

if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"Error setting Bus Count" withStatus: result]; return;}
```